# How can I sort Lists in the Quick Launch menu in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, quick-launch, sorting

I am creating several custom lists in SP 2007 according to the team's demands. These are displayed in the Quick Launch in the order that have been created, however I would like to know if I could sort the lists in a different order, e.g. **alphabetically**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use Publishing features? Normally you can changer order in Quick Launch settins from Site settings, Look and Feel column. You can find step by step guide here http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-items-in-the-quick-launch-of-sharepoint-sharepoint-2007  for example.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your post, it's been really helpful, easier than I thought. I do love your link because it's visual and fast to understand. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If publishing feature is enabled or you created site using publishing template, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-navigation-links-on-the-quick-launch-HA010255192.aspx#BM10

If not, you have to use code to sort it...Example here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2008/06/03/case-about-sorting-the-quick-launch-navigation.aspx